# Scrolling horizontally by full page on Space Bar key press

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scroll, keyboard-shortcuts

All major browsers allow vertical page scrolling by pressing the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> on the keyboard. However, this shortcut doesn't work if the page is entirely horizontal. Also, pressing the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys doesn’t work for going to beginning and end of page.

How can I remake this feature for horizontal scrolling with plain vanilla `JavaScript` (`ECMAScript 6`)?

Pressing the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> should scroll horizontally by `100vw`. The scrolling should ideally be animated with `behavior: "smooth"` effect.

Here is my `HTML` and `CSS` code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html { height: 100% }

html, body, section {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1
}

body {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
  overflow-x: auto
}

section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center
}

section:nth-of-type(1) { background: orange }
section:nth-of-type(2) { background: limeGreen }
section:nth-of-type(3) { background: royalBlue }

h2 { color: white }
```

```html
<section><h2>1</h2></section>
<section><h2>2</h2></section>
<section><h2>3</h2></section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) on a container, in your case `document.documentElement`, makes for a pretty convincing clone of the standard vertical <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> scrolling behaviour.

If you implement this on a full page that differs from your example, you should take care to change `container` to the proper element and change `window.innerWidth` if the scroll snap sections are not equal to `100vw`.

```js
// Set wrapAround to true to go back to 1 after 3
let scrollAmount = 0, wrapAround = true;
const container = document.documentElement;

window.onload = () => {
  document.body.onkeyup = (event) => {
    switch (event.code) {
      case 'Space': {
        scrollAmount += window.innerWidth

        if (wrapAround && scrollAmount >= container.scrollWidth) {
            scrollAmount = window.innerWidth * -1;
        }
        break;
      }
      case 'End': {
        scrollAmount = container.scrollWidth;
        break;
      }
      case 'Home': {
        scrollAmount = 0;
        break;
      }
      case 'PageDown': {
        scrollAmount += window.innerWidth

        if (wrapAround && scrollAmount >= container.scrollWidth) {
            scrollAmount = window.innerWidth * -1;
        }
        break;
      }
      case 'PageUp': {
        scrollAmount -= window.innerWidth
        
        if (wrapAround && scrollAmount < 0) {
            scrollAmount = container.scrollWidth;
        }
        break;
      }
    }

    container.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: scrollAmount,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  }
}

// Reset the scrollAmount if the user scrolls back manually
// If we wouldn't do this it would jump from 1 to 3 if the
// user scrolls back from 3 to 1 and presses space
window.onscroll = (event) => {
  scrollAmount = container.scrollLeft;
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html { height: 100% }

html, body, section {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1
}

body {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(100%);
  overflow-x: auto;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center
}

section:nth-of-type(1) { background: orange }
section:nth-of-type(2) { background: limeGreen }
section:nth-of-type(3) { background: royalBlue }

h2 { color: white }
```

```html
<section><h2>1</h2></section>
<section><h2>2</h2></section>
<section><h2>3</h2></section>
```

Comment: Hi Floris, thanks for providing such a comprehensive answer! For whatever reason, your code isn’t working when I run it on my local server. For this line: `document.body.onkeyup = (event) => {`, I get the following error: `null is not an object (evaluating 'document.body')`. And one more thing… When I run your code snippet here, the `End` isn't taking me to the end of the page, but `Home` does, so that’s great.

Comment: @Tzar That happens because document.body doesn't exist yet when the script is executed, you can circumvent that problem by moving the script tag to the end of the body, just before the `</body>` closing tag, or wrapping the `document.body` event listener assignment in a `window.onload` function. I've chosen for the latter and updated the snippet above. As a bonus, `Home` and `End` also scroll to the first and last page now, just like their regular vertical behaviour.

Comment: I just noticed I used [`event.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) in my snippet, which is deprecated. I switched it out for `event.code` and also added Page Up and Page Down, should you need it.

Comment: Brilliant move for adding `Page Up` and `Page Down`, which I totally forgot to aks for in the original question! Your code is super elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

you can use anchor for horizontal scrolling too ...
Little exemple here ( scroll on Space Bar )

```js
var page = 1;
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
      page ++; 
   location.hash = "#box-" + page;
    }
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #efefef;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

li > a {
    padding: 10px;
}

#content {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 250px; /*this is indicative*/
}

#content > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#content > div > p {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#box-1">link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#box-2">link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#box-3">link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#box-4">link 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#box-5">link 5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#box-6">link 6</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#box-7">link 7</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#box-8">link 8</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#box-9">link 9</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#box-10">link 10</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="content">
    <div id="box-1">
        <p>Some text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box-2">
        <p>Some text 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box-3">
        <p>Some text 3</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box-4">
        <p>Some text 4</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box-5">
        <p>Some text 5</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box-6">
        <p>Some text 6</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box-7">
        <p>Some text 7</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box-8">
        <p>Some text 8</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box-9">
        <p>Some text 9</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box-10">
        <p>Some text 10</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5up46L9v/5/ => ( better result with a highter snippet )

Smooth scrool in vanilla js is little hard for nothing for me ...
Use a lib like Jquery ...